# HDMI Switcher for analogue audio?

Tags: hdmi, rca

I ordered a 5 to 1 HDMI Switcher with remote. I was looking for the lowest price way to switch analogue audio RCA/3.5mm stereo. At the time I ordered this my decision was based on the availability of hdmi to rca audio cables. I know they make cables that are useless.

Is it possible to use any of the connections on the hdmi cable to switch analogue audio?

Or any thoughts on a low priced solution to switch analogue audio with a remote?

Thank You for all replies! Kevin

Answer (score 3):

No, it isn't possible.

An HDMI-to-RCA "cable" is really an active circuit that decodes the audio from the digital HDMI stream and converts it to analog. It takes advantage of the fact that the HDMI connector also has power on it.

The switch itself is active circuitry that is designed specifically to regenerate the high-speed serial data streams used in HDMI. There is no analog path through the switch.

On the input side, you would need a corresponding "RCA-to-HDMI" converter that digitizes the analog audio and encodes it into an HDMI stream. I don't think anyone makes these commercially, although there might be units that accept analog video + audio, and you could just ignore the video part.

But obviously, this is getting far away from your "lowest price" goal. You'd be far better served by getting something that's designed to switch analog audio directly. I'm not going to make any specific recommendations, because that would be off-topic here.

Comment: Thank You that's what I thought. Just wanted to check for sure!

Comment: Kevin, you can mark this as the correct answer. That way Dave gets the points.